# Silencing libcurl/pycurl PUT and POST

Tags: libcurl, pycurl

I have a python script which does a bunch of PUTs and POSTs, and when they are successful curl will output the updated html to stdout. I was wondering if there was a way to keep it from doing this? I don't really care about this information, so sending it to a file isn't necessary, but that seems to be the only solution I can find.

Comment: By 'curl', do you mean the pycurl Python module, or the 'curl' executable?  In any case, can you show a snippet of code?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the WRITEFUNCTION option in the Curl object.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
body = StringIO()
(...)
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, body.write)
```

Full example can be seen in [curl CVS repository](http://pycurl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pycurl/pycurl/tests/test_stringio.py?view=markup).